# Data set of software fault prediction studies

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, software

Currently I am working in software fault prediction. I want to perform some experiment in software fault prediction data set. But I am unable to find data set related to software fault prediction. Can anyone suggest me some link from where I can download these data sets?

Comment: Try server downtimes (as proxy for software and hardware failures). This data is publicly available.

Comment: You might also want to look into the literature relating modeling software reliability in a formal statistical sense. The work of Goel and Okumoto in the 1970-1990s provides a framework for that as well. If you look at the papers that cite these using google scholar, that's useful too.  http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5220566&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D5220566

Answer (score 2):

you can look at the software-artifacts infrastructure repository. this repository contains open source software with manually injected faults,test cases and scripts. This repository is available for everyone to use, we can conduct controlled experiments on these fault injected software.

http://sir.unl.edu/portal/index.php